# search in database with a typing mistakes

Tags: mysql, sql, database

we have database in our application which contain information about tracks or episodes like title, description ...etc.
Assume I have Title " يذهب الى المدرسة " and the user search with the word " إلى ", in Arabic the letter " ا " is different than " إ ", therefore the search will not give me any result since that word does not exist.

How can I search in database while including those typing mistakes?

The server is php and database is mysql.
If you know any guide or post to check, it would be appreciated.
Sorry if it this is wrong place to ask question. Thanks.

Comment: Normally, a "bad" search would simply turn up nothing, and that would be the expected behavior. However, if you want to allow typos, you might want to look into Soundex. In English using such a methodology, "Phil" would find both "Phil" and "Fill" etc.

Comment: unfortunately I need it, because we realized many users are doing those typing mistakes which lead to getting not good results. thanks

Comment: What is your database

Comment: So what about Soundex, as I suggested? Surely there is an Arabic version of it?

Comment: You could also see if there's an Arabic version of the Metaphone algorithm. It's more robust than Soundex. Barring that, you could implement the Levenshtein edit distance algorithm but I fear it would be very slow because it would require a table scan.

Comment: You can use and customize this function that is on Github, that will help you in some ways: https://github.com/m-kermani/combination

Answer (score 0):

Use soundex(column_name) = 'search_term'

Comment: Give it a try it might

Comment: I will try it later and let you know when after i test. thank you

Answer (score 0):

[DIFFERENCE()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188753.aspx) make a comparison of the two words using the phonetic score returned by [SOUNDEX()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187384.aspx). **This only works in English.**

Soundex was developed by Robert C. Russell and Margaret King Odell and patented in 1918 and 1922. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex)

The National Archives and Records Administration (NARA) maintains [the current rule set](http://www.archives.gov/research/census/soundex.html) for the official implementation of Soundex used by the U.S. Government.

In other languages you would have to create your own implementation to compare two words. Since a full phonetic implementation would be too complicated, you could create a function in which you compare a word, and account for the position and possible missing letters using the [LIKE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) operator.

Partial example:

```
SELECT @IsSimilar = 1 WHERE 'hello' LIKE 'Hel_o'

-- the underscore in TSQL matches a single character.
```